# Get the corresponding controlPoint from a component

Tags: maya, maya-api

The following commands will convert a given `controlPoint` index to the corresponding object's `component` type:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

print (mc.ls('pCube1.controlPoints[3]'))       # ['pCube1.vtx[3]']
print (mc.ls('nurbsSphere1.controlPoints[3]')) # ['nurbsSphere1.cv[0][3]']
print (mc.ls('ffd1Lattice.controlPoints[3]'))  # ['ffd1Lattice.pt[1][1][0]']
```

I am looking for a way to query the opposite: given a `component`, return its corresponding `controlPoint`. To do so I wrote a naïve solution that requires building a flattened list and then match the query for the proper index.

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import re

def naive_control_point_lookup(query):
    obj, comp  = query.split('.')
    comp_      = comp.split('[')[0]
    everything = mc.ls(f'{obj}.{comp_}[*]', fl=True) # flattened component list

    r = re.compile(f'.*{re.escape(comp)}')
    match = next(filter(r.match, everything)) # match the query's component
    return f'{obj}.controlPoints[{everything.index(match)}]' # format the index in a string


query = 'ffd1Lattice.pt[1][1][0]'
cp = naive_control_point_lookup(query) # ffd1Lattice.controlPoints[3]
print (query == mc.ls(cp)[0]) # True
```

This works, but I would think there is a way to directly obtain what I want.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to get this `component` --> `controlPoint` conversion done directly via a command, or via Maya's python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this can be done. You need to query the contents of the selection list using `MSelectionList::getDagPath()`, but make sure you capture the 'component' MObject from that call! *(it will store all the indices for the selected components)*

Then it will depend on the indexing used for the surface in question. You should be able to pass the returned component MObject to one of the following:

**MFnSingleIndexedComponent**: For meshes & curves

**MFnDoubleIndexedComponent**: For nurbs surfaces

**MFnTripleIndexedComponent**: For lattices

IIRC, you can also pass the `MObject` to an `MItGeometry` which will let you iterate over them in a unified fashion *(e.g. the indices returned will relate to the flattened points array indices, so you can use a single index for all of them)*. There are a few additional iterator types you can use if you want additional info *(e.g. `MItSurfaceCV`, `MItMeshVertex`, etc)*.

Comment: Thank you, i wasn't aware of MItGeometry (i think was introduced in Maya 2022) and its index method does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

A million thanks to @robthebloke for suggesting MItGeometry, which I wasn't aware of until now and lets me get what I want with no need for iteration or list building. Here's a code snippet to illustrate and complement his answer:

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om

def api_control_point_lookup(query):
    tracker = om.MSelectionList()
    tracker.add(query)   
        
    component = tracker.getComponent(0)
    index = om.MItGeometry(*component).index()
    
    obj = query.split('.')[0]
    return (f'{obj}.controlPoints[{index}]')

# works on vtx, cv and pt
print (api_control_point_lookup('pCube1.vtx[3]'))           # pCube1.controlPoints[3]
print (api_control_point_lookup('nurbsSphere1.cv[0][3]'))   # nurbsSphere1.controlPoints[3]
print (api_control_point_lookup('ffd1Lattice.pt[1][1][0]')) # ffd1Lattice.controlPoints[3]
```